# Automated email from dummy address through iOS app

Tags: ios, email, parse-platform

Let's say that I added the functionality to report something in my app. After the user reports that thing, I want an email sent to me from a dummy email address (NOT the user's email address) with details about why that thing was reported. Is there anyway to do this? Think "mailTo" function in PHP. It would be really userful. I am using parse.com if that helps. To reiterate, I want to AUTOMATICALLY sent an email from the app from a DUMMY email to my email. So no MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: you    want to do send email by your application or some other source as you said PHP. if you want to send automated email via ios app this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this with cloud code and a mandrill account. Check out this [post](http://blog.parse.com/2012/12/19/introducing-the-mandrill-cloud-module-for-transactional-emails/).

I have a setup like this:

`template.js`

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendTemplate", function(request, response) {
var Mandrill = require('cloud/mandrillTemplateSend.js');
Mandrill.initialize('SOMEKEY');
Mandrill.sendTemplate({
    template_name: "template name",
    template_content: [{
        name: "TEMPLATE CONTENT NAME",
        content: request.params.content
    }],
    message: {
        to: [{
            email: "EMAIL@EMAIL.COM",
            name: "NAME"
        }],
        important: true
    },
    async: false
}, {
    success: function (httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse);
        response.success("Email sent!");
    },
    error: function (httpResponse) {
        console.error(httpResponse);
        response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
    }
});
});
```

`mandrillTemplateSend.js`

```
var _apiUrl = 'mandrillapp.com/api/1.0';
var _apiKey = 'API KEY';

exports.initialize = function(apiKey) {
    _apiKey = apiKey;
};

exports.sendTemplate = function(request, response) {
    request.key = _apiKey;

    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        url: 'https://' + _apiUrl + '/messages/send-template.json',
        body: request,
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            response.success(httpResponse);
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            response.error(httpResponse);
        }
    });
};
```

You create a function in the cloud and call it from within your app when necessary. To learn about calling cloud functions you can visit parse documentation [here](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide).

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to set up a server that can send email, and make a request to the server from the app when you want to send an email. This is possible through a number of ways, as there are a bunch of APIs to do so. One of these APIs particularly of your interest might be SendGrid

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to directly send email from your code:

```
-(void)sendEmail
{
    NSString *htmlString = [self createAttachment];
    NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/html",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                               htmlString,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];


NSArray *pathsImage = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docspath = [pathsImage objectAtIndex:0];
pathsImage = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//    SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];

testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];

testMsg.fromEmail = [defaults objectForKey:@"fromEmail"];
testMsg.toEmail = [defaults objectForKey:@"toEmail"];
testMsg.bccEmail = [defaults objectForKey:@"bccEmal"];
testMsg.relayHost = [defaults objectForKey:@"relayHost"];
testMsg.requiresAuth = [[defaults objectForKey:@"requiresAuth"] boolValue];

if (testMsg.requiresAuth) {
    testMsg.login = [defaults objectForKey:@"login"];

    testMsg.pass = [defaults objectForKey:@"pass"];
}

testMsg.wantsSecure = [[defaults objectForKey:@"wantsSecure"] boolValue]; // 
testMsg.subject = @"Mersen Information(Final Email)";
testMsg.delegate = self;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [testMsg send];
});

}
```

Try it,

All the best!!!